# Parent does not wait for worker threads to complete task

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

In my program, the main thread creates 4 (or more) worker threads. At some point the parent (main thread) has to wait for the workers in order to complete some calculations. The threads are running on an endless loop so I can't use the `pthread_join(.., ..)` POSIX function in order to wait until the workers are done. So I am using a global counter and a condition variable.

**Main Thread Code**

```
unsigned jobs = 0; // global variable

// global mutex and cv. They get initialised in my main.
pthread_mutex_t counter_mutex;
pthread_cond_t  counter_cv;

static void process(..){

    jobs = myArray.size(); 

    // I am using a function here that broadcasts a cv in order to
    // wake up the workers

    pthread_mutex_lock(&counter_mutex); // lock counter
        while (jobs > 0){
            pthread_cond_wait(&counter_cv, &counter_mutex); // PARENT SHOULD GET STUCK HERE TILL WORKERS ARE DONE
        }
        // cout << "Workers are done" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&counter_mutex);   // unlock counter
}
```

**Workers Code**

```
 extern unsigned jobs;
 extern pthread_mutex_t counter_mutex;
 extern pthread_cond_t  counter_cv;

 void *run() {

    for (int i = 0;; i++) {

        // do some calculations here

        pthread_mutex_lock(&counter_mutex); // lock counter
            jobs--;
            if (jobs == 0){
                pthread_cond_signal(&counter_cv);
                cout << "All jobs are done" << endl;
            }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&counter_mutex);   // unlock counter

    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes my main thread does not get stuck at the condition variable in order to wait for the workers and that causes sometimes a segmentation fault. Is there any race condition that I can't see and that causes this problem?

Comment: How are you setting jobs initially?

Comment: jobs = myArray.size(); .. It's the number of the items in the queue/array that the workers pop and calculate.

Comment: Are there ever any threads active when you set jobs? There could be a race condition there since it's not locked. I'm not sure how that would cause the main thread to exit early though.

Comment: The threads are always active but stuck at another condition variable till the main thread pushes items to the queue/array.

Comment: Are you sure that the segfault is caused by the main thread not waiting? The code you've posted looks like it should work. In gdb you can use a breakpoint after the main thread gets past the condition and run `info threads` to see where are the threads are to confirm.

Comment: Yes I used gdb and 1 out of 20 times that I will execute the program, the main thread wont wait at the cv. At least that is what gdb says. Maybe the problem is not there. Thx anyway

Comment: Regardless of whether the main thread waits or not it should never get past the while loop until jobs is 0 (or less). You should log the value of jobs before and after you change it anywhere and see what the output is. Maybe that will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Do you have more working threads than jobs?

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I was thinking right now. I do not know the exact jobs size because I have multiple "job data flows" so I thought that if there are 3 jobs and i wake up 4 threads then the 3rd one will signal the cv and the 4th one will cause the segmentation maybe.

Comment: 3 jobs, 4 threads. I wake them all up. The 3 worker threads pop from the queue. The 4th pops what?? Then the third one decreases the jobs counter to 0, then signals the main thread and the 4th causes the sigsegv.

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious concurrency issue in your code. For the sake of simplicity, imagine that we have 2 workers, and 2 jobs left.  The following scenario could happen:

- Job count is set to 2
- The parent is stuck waiting for the condition variable
- Both workers start a processing iteration in their endless loop
- The first worker finishes its task faster for whatever reason, and executes the locked job count update. The job count is decremented to 1, so the parent is left waiting and the lock is released.  The worker then starts its next iteration. Unfortunately in reality there is no job left (1 was done, and 1 is currently performed by the second worker). But it starts an hypothetical job (perhaps addressing an array element that was in the meantime deleted or out of range ?)
- The second worker finishes its job, and the job count being decremented to 0, causing the parent to be awakened, holding the lock, exit the loop and unlock.
- You noted that while parent thinks it is over, the first worker still processing an hypothetical task, maybe trying to access `myArray` whereas it gets cleaned up, or whatever else could go wrong.

So you have two opportunity for races and/or segfalts: in the parent and in the still active worker, busy with a task that doesn't exist.

I think the worker loop would be much safer if you'd start the loop getting the lock, checking if there are still jobs remaining, and decrement upfront the job count, so that peer worker will know what's really left:

```
void *run() {

    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&counter_mutex); // lock counter
            if (jobs == 0){
                pthread_cond_signal(&counter_cv);
                cout << "All jobs are done" << endl;
            }
            else jobs--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&counter_mutex);   // unlock counter

        // do some calculations here

    }
}
```

The advantage is that worker only work if there is really work left.  The only trouble then, is that the parent is awaken by the first worker out of job. Other workers could however still be running.

If this is a problem you could for example maintain also a counter of still active jobs, and make the parent loop on  `(jobs>0 || active_jobs>0)`

Comment: There is a part of the code that I didnt add on the post where the workers when poppin from the queue/array check the size of it. So it is not possible to pop if the queue is empty. So when the first thread pops the size is now 1 but the jobs is not yet decremented. The 2nd thread pops and now the size is 0. 1st thread ends faster but decrements the jobs to 1 but it wont pop again cause the size of the queue is 0. I think my problem was caused by "spurious wake up" on a cond var in another part of my program. I edited it and it seems like it works. Thx

Comment: @pirox22 is the popping from the queue and size checking protected by the mutex ?

Answer (score 0):

The only trouble I see with your bits of code is that each worker will run like crazy (possibly at 100%CPU if your processing does not involve timers/IOs), and won't terminate once there are no more jobs.

In a real case your worker should get a job request from a queue or something similar, and block (waiting for an available job or some termination command) when there are no available jobs to process.

I see no race condition here. The only bug I see is the systematic decrementation of the job count. It will soon become negative and that could cause all sorts of troubles if you assume it cannot. To avoid that, simply test the counter to zero before decrementing it.